# Python/Twisted IRC bot logging problem

Tags: python, twisted, irc

Hey. I only recently started using Python, and my friend suggested using Twisted as a means to create this IRC bot, as it will be a lot simpler. Here is the code I have so far (which is heavily based off logbot.py haha)

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from twisted.words.protocols import irc
from twisted.python import log
import sys, time

class MessageLogger:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def log(self, message):
        timestamp = time.strftime("[%H:%M:%S]", time.localtime(time.time()))
        self.file.write('%s %s\n' % (timestamp, message))
        self.file.flush()

    def close(self):
        self.file.close()

class IRCProtocol(irc.IRCClient):
    nickname = "3n7rar3"
    def connectionMade(self):
        irc.IRCClient.connectionMade(self)
        self.logger = MessageLogger(open(self.factory.filename, "a"))

    def signedOn(self):
        print 'Success! Connection established.'
        self.join(self.factory.channels)
        print 'Joined channel', self.factory.channels

    def privmsg(self, user, channel, msg):
        user = user.split('!', 1)[0]
        self.logger.log("<%s> %s" % (user, msg))

class IRCFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = IRCProtocol
    channels = "#testing"

    def __init__(self, channel, filename):
        self.channel = channel
        self.filename = filename

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection failed because of %s" % reason
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection lost: %s" % reason
        connector.connect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
    host, port = "irc.freenode.net", 6667
    fact = IRCFactory(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
    reactor.connectTCP(host, port, fact)
    reactor.run()
```

The problem with this is that the bot only logs channel messages, but I would also like it to log channel joins and parts. What is the easiest way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define methods for joins and parts and log inside them too:

```
def userJoined(self, user, channel):
    log.msg('%s has joined %s' % (user, channel))

def userLeft(self, user, channel):
    log.msg('%s has left %s' % (user, channel))

def userQuit(self, user, quitMessage):
    log.msg('%s has quit. Reason: %s' % (user, quitMessage))
```

The [api documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.words.protocols.irc.IRCClient.html) and [source code](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-10.2.0/twisted/words/protocols/irc.py) are probably useful for you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.words.protocols.irc.IRCClient.html) seems pretty clear to me.  Override the `userJoined` and `userLeft` methods like you did for `privmsg`.

Comment: I was looking at the wrong documentation haha. Thanks, appreciate it.